# bringSubviewToFront not working with dropdown view (UIView)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

I have a dropdown view (it'a `UIView` with a `UITableView` fully embedded in it). The top anchor is programmatically constrained to the bottom anchor of a `UIButton` so that when you touch the button, the dropdown view opens. See code below

However, my problem lies in the fact that the height of the open dropdown view is `150`, and the only part shown of the view is the part inside the `UITableViewCell` (see image), with the bottom part hidden behind the cell.

```
func genderDropdownViewConfig() {
    genderDropdownView.backgroundColor = .red
    genderDropdownView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    genderDropdownView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    genderDropdownButton.addSubview(genderDropdownView)
    //genderDropdownButton.bringSubview(toFront: genderDropdownView)
    //tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0))?.superview?.addSubview(genderDropdownView)
    //tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0))?.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: genderDropdownView)

    genderDropdownButton.addSubview(genderDropdownView)
    tableView.bringSubview(toFront: genderDropdownButton)

    genderDropdownView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: genderDropdownButton.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    genderDropdownView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: genderDropdownButton.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    genderDropdownView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: genderDropdownButton.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    //genderDropdownHeight = genderDropdownView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
    genderDropdownHeight = genderDropdownView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)

    for subview in genderDropdownView.subviews {
        subview.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you added the button and the dropdown view inside a tableview's cell?

Comment: @MohamadSheikh yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cell's height size needs to be redefined by your dropDownView. It seems that your cell contentView's height don't have any connection with your dropDownView's height to reform itself.

I think you should update the height after the button tapped.
You can try this code to update your cell's height.

```
cell.contentView.size.height = dropDownView.frame.origin.y + dropDownView.frame.height
```

Comment: This was the way to go, instead of doing it this way though, I reconfigured the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` func, and then called `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: That's correct too while reloading the whole tableView because of the height of the one cell isn't recommended. Should try to reload the tableView when the dataSource changed.

Comment: Also, sorry, this has made the `UITableView` not respond to cell touches, despite `isUserInteractionEnabled = true` - any ideas?

Comment: Would you pls put your code here on how do you call for selecting?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is with the way you add the genderDropdownView to the layout.

Try to add the genderDropdownView to cell's main view by

`cell.view.addSubview(genderDropdownView)`

and then ask the cell's view to bring the dropdown view to front.

```
cell.view.bringSubview(toFront: genderDropdownButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to how your layers are defined from the storyboard, it looks like your label "current weight" is forcing your dropdown view to make itself smaller. Maybe define a height constraint for the dropdown section?

Comment: I have already defined a height constraint for it. When it is not shown, it is deactivated and equal to `0`, whilst when it is shown, it is activated and equal to `150`.